# Mapping new command involving <escape> clear all predefined <escape> commands

Tags: key-bindings

I have the command `fill-paragraph` mapped to key `<escape> q`, it is mapped by default in emacs.

Now I want to map the opposite command, `unfill-paragraph`, to key `<escape> p`.

However, when I do this all predefined commands with `<escape>` stops working. I need to explicitly remap all of them.

I am mapping the command like this:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape> p" ) 'unfill-paragraph)
```

Is this the expected behavior? How can I map new commands to `escape` keys without clearing all predefined?

Comment: IMHO: Don't fiddle with `<escape>`. It's possible, but there are too many hard-coded thingies to work around (e.g. `ESC ESC ESC`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the command `fill-paragraph` mapped to key `<escape> q`, it is mapped by default in emacs.

In fact, it's mapped to `ESC q` by default, which is slightly different.  `ESC` is the ascii escape character, while `<escape>` is the keyboard key at top left of your keyboard (but if you're using Emacs from a text terminal, the terminal probably sends `ESC`, not `<escape>`, when you press that key).  When there is no binding for `<escape>` Emacs will translate it to `ESC` and lookup bindings for `ESC` instead.

So if you map your `unfill-paragraph` to `ESC p` things should work as you expect:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC p" ) 'unfill-paragraph)
```

Note that `ESC <key>` is equivalent to `M-<key>` (i.e., you can probably use `Alt+p` and `Alt+q` as well, see [(emacs) User Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html))